# Avoiding duplicate creation of old question to elicit new answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was wondering how **not to create a duplicate question of an old one** while asking for fresh infos on this specific question.

In short, is there a way to "up" an old question to ask people if they have new answers ? Example :
 [Running and debugging PyQGIS scripts in PyCharm Community Edition?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118950/running-and-debugging-pyqgis-scripts-in-pycharm-community-edition)

If I would like to "ask again" this 3 year old question for actual answers, what could I do to make it live again ? I guess a simple comment doesn't make it go up, and an edit would probably do the trick, but I feel it's not the right way.

It's an example, I think I have found an answer to it here :
 https://nathanw.net/2014/05/10/setting-up-pycharm-for-pyqgis-and-qt/

Answer (score 2):

Hum...just found myself the answer to my own question : **set up a bounty on the question** will pull it up and attract attention to it. I guess asking the question brought the answer to my brain :)